# The repository 'cdrom://Lubuntu 20.04.4 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20220223) focal Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, lubuntu, repository

i write `sudo apt-get update` and the ubuntu show me

```
E: The repository 'cdrom://Lubuntu 20.04.4 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20220223) focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

error.
how to fix it?!

Comment: You should be able to unselect it from Settings -> Software & Updates -> Other Software

Comment: The most appropriate Lubuntu manual page is https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/4/4.3/software_sources.html in case it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have a CD-ROM repo when the CD-ROM does not exist aka removed.
So you can just remove the repo here's how

discover:
Go to the cdrom:// entry and un check it

Or with gnome just go to the `software center` and go to other software and uncheck the cdrom:// entry